# Symfony 4.1 ReflectionException : Class does not exist

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I keep getting error "ReflectionException : Class does not exist" when access

```
$em = $args->getEntityManager()
$obj = $args->getEntity()    
$meta = $em->getClassMetadata((new \ReflectionClass($obj))->getName());
```

When I print $meta and exit the process, it seems OK and returns value.
I already tried some solutions: dump autoload, require symfony/form and symfony/config. But I still have no clue.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to get FieldNames, FieldType, and FieldValue from an entity metadata

Comment: get_class() is your friend, no need for reflection